# How to express the estimation result

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I would like to ask you how to express the following regression analysis.

$Y=a+bX+cZ+u$

I want to mention that $b$ is significant.
In this case, which sentence in the following correct?

(1) The coefficient of $X$ on which $Y$ is regressed is significant.

(2) The regression coefficients of $X$ to $Y$ are significant.

(3) The regression coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is significant.

I think (1) is grammatically correct, but redundant.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If this is homework. It needs the `self-study` tag. See [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: (2) and (3) are unlikely to be expressed by a native English speaker.  Most people would avoid any of (1), (2), and (3) because they are all ambiguous.  This seems to be a question of English usage rather than statistics and so would perhaps be better off asked at https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

All are appropriate, depending on context.

Though I suggest adding the p value somewhere in your conclusion, as this allows the reader to assess how good the fit is for him/herself. This is especially helpful if you have several competing models to compare.

Comment: (2) Is not always true.